# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException with Container-Managed Transaction

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb

I use JPA 2.1 with EclipseLink 2.5 + EJB 3.2 + Glassfish 4.0 with a Derby database for development.

When I try to persist an entity through the EntityManager I get the following exception:

```
2014-05-15T18:17:13.775+0200|SEVERE: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:161)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:281)
    at hu.gombost.store.jee.data.user.UserServiceImpl.create(UserServiceImpl.java:37)
    at hu.gombost.store.jee.data.user.UserServiceImpl.create(UserServiceImpl.java:1)
    at hu.gombost.store.jee.web.Register.submit(Register.java:35)
    at hu.gombost.store.jee.web.Register$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.submit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have an EJB for handling the User entity:

```
@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserServiceLocal {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    public Long create(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        return user.getId();
    }

}
```

And here's my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="store-jee-data" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/storedb</jta-data-source>

        <!-- classes omitted -->

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform"/>  
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/storedb;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sa" />

            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> 
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both" />

        </properties>   
</persistence-unit>
```

I don't see what I'm missing here so I'm a bit puzzled. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How do you instantiate UserServiceImpl?

Comment: I inject it with CDI: @Inject private UserServiceLocal userService;

Comment: Same code in a brand new project (with the only difference of persistence.xml settings - I don't generate the tables) is not enough to reproduce the issue. Give it a try.

Comment: I grabbed a clean Glassfish copy and now it works for me too. Thank you for your effort!